# Moving specific files into a folder based on directory using Command Prompt

Tags: command-line, prompt, command-line-arguments

I have a series of about 100 folders called E101,E102....E200. Within each of these folders is a file called calquip.docx and calquon.docx

I would like to move calquip.docx and calquon.docx into a folder within its directory. For example in directory /E101 I want to create a folder called "cal" which will contain calquip.docx and calquon.docx

To reiterate every folder from E101 to E200 has a calquip.docx and calquon.docx file. I want to move that file into a folder within each parent folder.

I have to do this for all the folders. Surely there has to be a way to do this but I can't wrap my head around it.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

A simple batch script should help with this. Here's a sample I wrote in a few minutes, which might be a good starting point. This assumes the batch script is in the same directory containing your directories:

```
@echo off

for /L %%n in (101, 1, 200) do (
    cd E%%n
    mkdir cal
    move calquip.docx cal\calquip.docx 1> nul
    move calquon.docx cal\calquon.docx 1> nul
    cd ..
)
```